# Adding more than 1 item to "1 to many" property in SwiftData crashes preview / sim

Tags: swift-data

I am trying to setup data in the app during the first launch using SwiftData. If I try to add multiple items to a "1 to many" property, the app crashes.

I am stuck figuring how to make this work. Sample code below:

```
import SwiftUI
import SwiftData

class Persistance {
    static var previewModelContainer: ModelContainer = {
        let schema = Schema([
            MyList.self,
            MyItem.self,
        ])
        let modelConfiguration = ModelConfiguration(schema: schema, isStoredInMemoryOnly: true)

        do {
            
            let container=try ModelContainer(for: schema, configurations: [modelConfiguration])
            
            //INITING LIST AND ITEMS
            let list=MyList()
            list.name="first list"
            
            let item1=MyItem()
            item1.name="item 1 name"
            print("item1 created")
            
            list.items.append(item1)
            print("item1 added to list")
            
            let item2=MyItem()
            item2.name="item 2 name"
            print("item2 created")
            
            list.items.append(item2)
            print("item2 added to list")
            
            let actor=PersistanceActor(modelContainer: container)
            Task {
                await actor.insert(list)
                print("list added to store")
            }
            
            return container
        } catch {
            fatalError("Could not create ModelContainer: \(error)")
        }
    }()
    
}


actor PersistanceActor: ModelActor {
    let modelContainer: ModelContainer
    let modelExecutor: any ModelExecutor
    
    init(modelContainer: ModelContainer) {
        self.modelContainer = modelContainer
        let context = ModelContext(modelContainer)
        modelExecutor = DefaultSerialModelExecutor(modelContext: context)
    }
    
    func save() {
        do {
            try modelContext.save()
        }catch {
            print("error inserting")
        }
    }

    func insert<T:PersistentModel>(_ value:T) {
        do {
            modelContext.insert(value)
            try modelContext.save()
        }catch {
            print("error inserting")
        }
    }
    
    func delete<T:PersistentModel>(_ value:T) {
        do {
            modelContext.delete(value)
            try modelContext.save()
        }catch {
            print("error inserting")
        }
    }
    
    func get<T:PersistentModel>(_ descriptor:FetchDescriptor<T>)->[T]? {
        var toReturn:[T]?
        do {
            toReturn=try modelContext.fetch(descriptor)
        }catch {
            print("error inserting")
        }
        return toReturn
    }
    
}

@main
struct TestingSDApp: App {
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            LaunchUIView()
        }
        .modelContainer(Persistance.previewModelContainer)
    }
}

struct LaunchUIView: View {
    
    @Environment(\.modelContext) private var context
    
    @Query var list:[MyList]
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ForEach(list, id: \.name) { item in
                MyListItem(item: item)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct MyListItem: View {
    let item:MyList
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ForEach(item.items, id: \.self) { item in
                Text("\(item.name ?? "no item name")")
            }
        }
    }
}

#Preview {
    LaunchUIView()
        .modelContainer(Persistance.previewModelContainer)
}

@Model
class MyList {
    
    var name:String?=""
    
    @Relationship(deleteRule: .cascade, inverse: \MyItem.myList)
    var items:[MyItem]=[MyItem]()
    
    init() {
        
    }
}

@Model
class MyItem {
    var name:String?=""
    var myList:MyList?
    
    init() {
        
    }
}
```

if i comment out the
list.items.append(item2)
the code seems to work.

Any suggestions highly appreciated.

Comment: insert each item/list before you append, I think there is a faulting issue with SwiftData

Comment: Hello Iorem, I've been trying to resolve this issue and this is my current finding: If I have an object with "1-many" relationship, this object needs to be inserted into swiftdata before ANY attempt to append more than ONE of the "many" items. I've just tested this on my JSON dump with sample data. Thanks for your comment. Regards Libor

Comment: Submit a bug report and post the feedback number so others can reference